# Putting undetermined number of views into a layout in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

If I define a layout using XML, but I want to populate it with some number n, of ImageViews, hwhat is the best way to go about doing this?

If I wanted to put in a single IMageView, I could easily put it in the XML of the layout, but if n (the number) is only known at runtime, I can't really add this to the XML script (can I)?

The two ways I have so far (neither of which I like) are:

- Forget XML, just do the whole layout in Java. Laborious
- Add the ImageViews in the Java code thus:

  thelayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

  setContentView(thelayout);

  for(int i = 0; i < n;i++){

  thelayout.addView(new ImageView(this));
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your layout in XML with a LinearLayout (or even better, a ListView, ScrollView or something like that) somewhere, then in code add your ImageViews to this layout. This way you can add the images in code and define the rest of the UI in XML.

Comment: Well, the only other ways I can think of are defining the entire layout in code, which isn't very nice, or generating new XML and parsing it, which is just horrible.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the presentation you want.

For example, there is a built-in widget called `Gallery`, and here is an example of setting it up

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html

Its docs describe it as

> A view that shows items in a center-locked, horizontally scrolling list.

so if you want something different than that you would probably have to create your own `View`. If you want vertical images in the same way you could use a `ListView` with a custom adapter.